# How to use mapfile and several arrays?

Tags: bash, map-files

In my last ask, I learned how to use mapfile to get a bit of text into an array. But when trying to loop it through the file I found it only got the first part of the text file and not any other lines. I think I might be missing a way to check/read through several arrays in the file.

patron.txt =

```
123456:Gerald:012-9999999:asdf@gmail.com
999999:Tom:010-8888888:zxcv@gmail.com
```

Current Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Search Patron Details"
echo -n "Enter Patron ID: "
read id1
mapfile -d: -t array < <(grep -i "$id1" patron.txt)
echo "Fullname (auto display): ${array[1]}"
echo "Contact Number (auto display): ${array[2]}"
echo "Email Adddress (auto display): ${array[3]}"
echo -n "Would you like to continue searching for patrons? (y)es or (q)uit: "
read option
case $option in
 y|Y) bash show_details;;
 q|Q) bash main_menu;;
 *) echo "Invalid entry";;
esac
```

Intended Result:

```
Search Patron Details
Enter Patron ID: 999999
Fullname (auto display): Tom
Contact Number (auto display): 010-8888888
Email Adddress (auto display): zxcv@gmail.com
999999
Would you like to continue searching for patrons? (y)es or (q)uit: y

Search Patron Details
Enter Patron ID: 123456
Fullname (auto display): Gerald
Contact Number (auto display): 012-9999999
Email Adddress (auto display): asdf@gmail.com
```

Actual Result:

```
Search Patron Details
Enter Patron ID: 999999
Fullname (auto display): Gerald
Contact Number (auto display): 012-9999999
Email Adddress (auto display): asdf@gmail.com
999999
Would you like to continue searching for patrons? (y)es or (q)uit: y
Search Patron Details
Enter Patron ID: 123456
Fullname (auto display): Gerald
Contact Number (auto display): 012-9999999
Email Adddress (auto display): asdf@gmail.com
```

This is from lessons of classrooms, we have limited shell knowledge.

Comment: Your grep does not search for a patron id, but for a line in patron.txt which matches the pattern `$id1` anywhere in the line. Since Geralds phone number contains 999999, this id picks Gerald and Tom as well.

Comment: You just miss `^` before `$id` as `grep` argument: `mapfile -d: -t array < <(grep -i  "^$id1" patron.txt)`

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. See [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a perfect answer, but substitute your grep

```
grep -i "$id1" patron.txt
```

with this:

```
grep -i "^$id:" patron.txt
```

Thanks to the "^", the searched term must reside at the beginning of the line.

Thanks to the trailing ":", the searched term must end with ":" which is also the field separator. In other word, this grep searches the records having $id as first field.

Note also that, this way, you can not search anymore for partial matches. To do that, one should first isolate the first field and then perform a search on it (more complicated).

Answer (score 1):

Um, why so complicated? Just use `awk`:

```
$ awk -v id=123456 -F: '$1 == id{printf "Name: %s\nNumber: %s\nEmail: %s\n", $2,$3,$4}' patron.txt 
Name: Gerald
Number: 012-9999999
Email: asdf@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do, re-using the maximum of your previous code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Search Patron Details"
echo -n "Enter Patron ID: "
read id1
array=( $(awk -F':' -v OFS=" " -v id=$id1 '$1==id{$1=$1}1' < patron.txt) )
cat<<EOF
Fullname (auto display): ${array[2]}
Contact Number (auto display): ${array[3]}
Email Adddress (auto display): ${array[4]}
EOF
```

Or using only `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Search Patron Details"
echo -n "Enter Patron ID: "
read id1
mapfile lines < file
for line in "${lines[@]}"; do
    IFS=: read id name phone email <<< "$line"
    if ((id==id1)); then
        cat<<EOF
        Fullname (auto display): $name
        Contact Number (auto display): $phone
        Email Adddress (auto display): $email
EOF
    fi
done < file
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't even scarcely understand what's going on with the array...

Comment: It definitely works, but I haven't the foggiest of what's going on.

Comment: Don't you know a bit of awk?

Comment: It was never covered in class. Sorry for not knowing.

Comment: It's the basics from shell.

Comment: Added pure bash solution

Comment: *"...I haven't the foggiest..."*. Learn to execute code, one-line at a time in another terminal window. Take multi-cmd steps apart, and add back, to see what each step is doing. Worst, case, `echo varOfInterest=x${varOfInterest}X"`. etc. This is true for any prog. language you will use (some languages will have better tools). Once you understand better what is happening, you will have a mental picture of what a step should do, and you can condense your debugging into larger steps. Many times you will be able to see it without any debugging steps. How to you get to Carnegie Hall? Practice (-;